# why the extra .change() or trigger('change') after .change(func());

Tags: jquery, triggers, onchange

We see that the examples in both the following implement the extra .trigger('change') after .change(funct(//does something)). I got rid of the change() for the first example in jsfiddle and it still works. I don't get why they manually trigger change in the end ?

http://api.jquery.com/change/
http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>change demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    color: red;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select name="sweets" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Chocolate</option>
  <option selected="selected">Candy</option>
  <option>Taffy</option>
  <option selected="selected">Caramel</option>
  <option>Fudge</option>
  <option>Cookie</option>
</select>
<div></div>

<script>
$( "select" )
  .change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str += $( this ).text() + " ";
    });
    $( "div" ).text( str );
  })
  .change(); // why this line? 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your JS Fiddle.

Comment: server is really slow right now. http://jsfiddle.net/aw8pazro/ so you see the .change() commented out in the end but code still works

Comment: I do not see your fiddle code producing a result.

Comment: try change to jquery 1.10..server too slow for me to change it

Comment: yea. it works for me, tho very slow.  but you see the .change() in the end? so when the select option changes, an onchange event should be fired automatically. there's really no need for a manual trigger, right?

Comment: It does not work until you change the selection.  That's why I didn't notice any action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are talking about:

```
$(function() {
    $('.selector').change(function() {
        //do something
    }).change(); // <<======
});
```

The last `.change()` triggers the `change` event when the page loads. The logic is, if the `.selector` element has a default value that you would like used in some way as when it's value changes, you trigger the `change` event on page load. **And you can do the same with any event.**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/2ugroq3o/)

```
$(function() {
    $('.city').change(function() {
        alert( this.value );
    }).change();
});
```

1. When the demo loads it will alert the first `option` in the `select` element because of `.change()`
2. To verify, remove `.change()` and click Run; the will be no alert except when you select a different city.

Comment: hmmm i don't understand what you said about use the default value so you trigger on load. Can you explain?

Comment: I'll post an example briefly. It would have made everything all much easier if you had posted your code.

Comment: oh i see. it's all just so the change event and subsequently the handler is triggered on load.